# C* migrations- move 1B+ rows table data to new schema table

Tags: mysql, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I working with DSE 4.7 datastax-enterprise, C* 2.1.5, spark 1.2.1, and need to migrate the data from a big table to new empty table with different schema and additional column that need to be generated from one of the excising columns in the big table.

I know that migration of table data to another table with new schema can be done by **spark** or by copy command to csv file in **cqlsh**, but I am interested in a **tool** that can give me long term solution for future migrations and more options as managing and planing migrations.

I think that it is a common problem and I didn't find any solid solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Data frames aren't available until 1.4 so you'd have to upgrade. I'll share an example job that you can start with and tweak for your use case.

Comment: Check it out https://github.com/rssvihla/spark_commons/blob/master/examples/spark_bulk_operations/src/main/scala/pro/foundev/scala/SchemaMigration.scala

Comment: Here https://github.com/rssvihla/spark_commons/blob/master/examples/spark_bulk_operations/src/main/scala/pro/foundev/scala/CassandraCapable.scala#L69

Comment: Spark is the most flexible tool for this. Maybe try Cassandra loader + awk? http://www.sestevez.com/brians-loader-unloader-for-search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been convinced that Spark is the best tool for the job.
I have tested the below code and the results are good.

```
import java.sql.Date
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext}
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import java.sql._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._


object Migration {
  def main(args: scala.Array[String]) {

    def changeDate(created: java.util.Date) : String = {
        var sDate = new DateTime(created)
        var sDay = sDate.getDayOfMonth()
        var sMonth = sDate.getMonthOfYear()
        var sYear = sDate.getYear()
        var created_date = "" + sYear + "-" + sMonth + "-" + sDay
        created_date //return
    }

    //spark configuration
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("migration")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val connector = CassandraConnector(conf)

    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table_a")

    println("Starting migration...")

    rdd.map(row => { 
        val x = new java.util.Date(row.getLong("x"))
        val y = new java.util.Date(row.getLong("y"))
        val z = row.getString("z")
        val t = row.getString("t")
        val k = changeDate(x)

        connector.withSessionDo(session => {
            val statement = session.prepare(s"INSERT INTO keyspace.table_b (k, y, z, x, t) " + "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
            val bound = statement.bind(k, y, z, x, t)
            session.executeAsync(bound)
        })
    }).foreach(x => x.getUninterruptibly())

    println("Done.")



 } }
```